# Split in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, split

I am looking for a way to split a string using Postgresql from a table.
For example, the out put of table is like :
`https://www.test.ir/` 
The expected result is like :
`test` 
I have found to do this by javascript:

```
  var Text = 'https://www.test.ir/'
  var splText= Text.split('.')
  console.log(splText[1])
```

How can I do it by Postgresql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the following makes sense to resolve your purpose:

```
select split_part('https://www.test.ir/','.',2)||'/'
```

Comment: Thanks @Touhidul Islam for your answer, Firstly what does `||'/'` mean in your code? secondly I have this error: `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): SQL logic error or missing database
no such function: split_part `

Comment: 1) By ||, I am concatenating 'test' with '/', which outputs 'test/'
2) This syntax will only work for Postgresql, looking at your Error, it seems you are try to run the sql query in SQLite DB Client platform.